# bootstrap datatable pdf button click not working on arabic words

Tags: bootstrap-4, arabic

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I am using bootstrap datatable, On click of pdf button Arabic words is not showing properly on the pdf file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Got any error ? "not showing properly" is it showing at all ?

Comment: No there is no error  but on PDF file the Arabic words is not displaying.